# Accessing a .jpg file that is in a Jar

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have a question about accessing a .jpg file that is contained within a ant generated java jar file.  My java project contains Java code and some .jpg files that I use. I want to be able to reference that .jpg file and be able to copy from jar to a directory.

Is there any way to that or do I always have to keep the jar outside of the jar file?

Comment: *"I want to be able to reference that .jpg file.."* That is easy enough.  *"..and be able to copy from jar to a directory."*  Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can import the jar as a library into your project and access the resources directory or wherever you placed the JPG if you want to reference it directly from your project.

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are just .zip's with a manifest. If you know where in the jar file the jpg is place, you just need to unzip the jar and copy the jpg to the desired location.

Comment: You could add that this will work if you need the image as a separate file from the jar. Otherwise, you could use @sjakubowski method.